# Net::SSH::Authentication failed while cap deploy

Tags: git, deployment, ssh, bitbucket

I am trying to `deploy code` on `server` then got error below:

```
** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: xx.xx.xxx.xxx (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@xx.xx.xxx.xxx.)
connection failed for: xx.xx.xxx.xxx (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@ip)
```

What is issue. I am not finding any solution.

Any one have.

Thanks

Comment: which version of `net-ssh` are you using ? many users reported issues with 2.8 so generally reverting back to 2.7 works

Comment: Using net-ssh 3.1 something...